# Any reason not to put stored procs independent of specific database in mysql's mysql database?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb

I've never wanted to touch the database actually named "mysql" (the one with tables proc, slow_log, user, etc) unless doing something officially supported with it.  By this, I mean I wouldn't create new tables in it, etc.

But, if I'm creating a few stored procedures that operate on any database and aren't specific to a single one, is it appropriate to store those to the "mysql" database, or would it be better to create a "genericStoredProcs" database to put them in that had no tables?

Comment: That would be strange. have never seen anyone creating a separate DB just to have few stored procedure which operates on cross DB's

Comment: @Rahul with prepared statements sometimes, using passed parameters. So yes, best to keep it separate, lest you forget what you are doing and mess with DDL stmts against `user` or the like

Comment: @Drew, Ahh!! make sense and in such case I would say then store them in `MySQL` DB (`master` DB in SQL Server) rather than having a separate DB alltogether.

Comment: Problem is the tendency to then say, geez, I need some common tables. Ooo, which ones do I delete, I forget my naming conventions (if I even had any)

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend adding *any* objects to the `mysql` database.

It might be possible to do that, and it might be supported. But I wouldn't take that risk. That's just asking for trouble. Just let the mysql database be what it's supposed to be, let it do what it's supposed to do, and don't muck with it.

If you need a database to store "shared" objects, then create a new database, and grant appropriate privileges.

Comment: More caution: The Oracle next release, 8.0, is doing some major upheavals in `mysql`.